# How to display the particular tag in a file like description in the listview dynamically using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to get the some data from file like some.txt. I want to display some data in that file like description under the each list in the listview.

```
$(xml).find('section[order="' + order + '"] content').each(function () {
        var content = $(this).text();
        var seq = order + '' + $(this).attr('order');
        var file = $(this).attr('file');
        $("#content").append('<li><a href="#" data-sequence="s' + seq + '" file="' + file + '">' + content + ' </a> </li> ');
    });
    $("#content").listview('refresh');
});
```

In the above code i created the listview.Now I changed the code as below:

```
$("#content_list").append('<li><a href="#" file="' + file +'">' + content + ' </a><p class="description text"></p> </li> ');


$(".description").each(function() {
        $(".text").load(file, function() {
                var txt = $(this).find('I').text();
                $("#content_list").append('<p>' + txt + '</p>');

            });
 });
```

In the above code "file" attribute contains some .txt file. By using this file i want to get some data to display the text as the description for the heading in the list.I tried in many ways but the whole file is displaying.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You started your code `.ready` which is not recommended to use with jQuery Mobile ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1771795)) I replaced it with `pageinit` which is equivalent to `.ready` but designed to work with jQuery Mobile.

.`load` wasn't used properly; you needed to read retrieved (*data*) from the loaded file this way.

```
$('#files').load(file, function (data) {
 var txt = $(data).find('i').text();
 .......
});
```

Here is the new [code](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/TdF8v/).