# How to insert HTML into div on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have spent quite a while searching SO for a good answer to my question, but nothing quite hit the mark...so here goes. I'm working with jquery, javascript, html, and jquery-mobile to create an e book of sorts.  There is a table of contents that is accessible from a slide panel on every content page.  The table of contents, which is a set of nested li and ul elements, contains html that is repeatedly used on every page. If you're familiar with jquery mobile, I'm inserting this list hierarchy within the `<div data-role=panel>` section, to create the collapsible list elements within the slide panel.  Right now, the way I'm doing this is by putting the exact same table of contents code on every page.  Obviously, this is a terrible way to do this.  I need to find a way to embed this table of contents code into every page that requires it, so that I must only update the table of contents once when a change is made, instead of updating it on every single page.  Right now I'm doing it like this...

```
<div data-role="panel" id="TOC" data-icon="grid" data-display="overlay">
                <script>
                    $('#TOC').load('example.TOC.html')
                </script> 

            </div> <!--This is the end of the slide panel section-->
```

The html is loading, but it doesn't have access to jquery mobile, jquery, or any of the external javascript files I've created.  I'm trying to understand why. I'm loading all of the resources in the `<head>` and the table of contents is being loaded in the `<body>`.  So, you would think this would work... but the only way I can get the slide panel to work properly is if I copy the head section to the table of contents file.  Sorry for that lengthy explanation...but here is some code to clarify.

> ```
> <!doctype html> <html>
> <head>
>     <title class="link-1-1-1-2" <!--id="link-1-1-1-2"--> >Part 2</title> 
>     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
>         <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"></link>
>
>         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
>         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
>         <script src="../Support/js/jStorage.js"></script>
>         <script src="../Support/js/bookmark2.js"></script>
>         <script src="../Support/js/linknavigation.js"></script>
>
>
> </head>
> <body>
>     <div data-role="page">
>
>
>
>         <!--begin header-->
>         <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
>             <a data-icon="grid" href="#TOC">Table of Contents</a>
>             <h1>Part 2</h1>
>             <button data-icon="check" id="bookmarkPage"> Bookmark </button>
>         </div><!-- /header -->
>
>         <!--begin content-->
>         <div data-role="content">
>             <p> The content of the page would go here </p>
>         </div><!-- /content -->
>
>
>         <!--begin footer-->
>         <div data-role="footer" data-id="navigation-bottom" data-position="fixed" class="ui-bar">
>             <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">               
>                 <button data-icon="back" data-theme="a" id="previous"> Previous</button>    
>                 <button data-icon="forward" data-theme="a" id="next"> Next</button>
>             </div>
>         </div><!--footer-->
>
>
>         <!--Create a slide panel with the table of contents-->
>         <div data-role="panel" id="TOC" data-icon="grid" data-display="overlay">
>             <script>
>                 $('#TOC').load('example.TOC.html')
>             </script> 
>
>         </div> <!--This is the end of the slide panel section-->
>
>     </div><!-- /page -->
>
> </body>
>  </html>
> ```

UPDATE:  I'm adding the code for example.toc.html so that you guys can see everything that's going on.

```
 <!--These first lines are required to get the table of contents working, but cause other 
issues-->  
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Support/js/jStorage.js"></script>
    <script src="../Support/js/bookmark2.js"></script>
    <script src="../Support/js/linknavigation.js"></script>-->


    <!--create a navbar for the top-->
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true"> 
        <button data-icon="plus" data-theme="a" id="openAll">Expand All</button>
        <button data-icon="minus" data-theme="a"id="closeAll">Collapse All</button>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->



    <!--Give the panel some control buttons from out linknavigation.js file-->
    <!--Give the panel some control buttons from out linknavigation.js file-->
    <div data-role="controlgroup" >
        <button data-icon="plus"    data-mini="true"  data-theme="a" id="openSome"> Expand Some</button>    
        <button data-icon="minus"   data-mini="true"  data-theme="a" id="closeSome"> Collapse Some</button>
        <button data-icon="arrow-d" data-mini="true"  data-theme="a" id="expandBookmarks">View Bookmarks</button>
        <button data-icon="delete"  data-mini="true"  data-theme="a" id="clearBookmarks"> Clear Bookmarks </button>
    </div>


<!--Create list structure....this is not an ideal solution...need a way to reference this structure externally-->
<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" class="expandable depth-1">
    <h3>Chapter 1</h3>
    <ul data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-2">
        <h3> Unit 1 </h3>
        <ul data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-3">
            <h3>Section 1</h3>
            <!--<li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 1</h3>I'm Part 1</li>-->
            <a data-role="button" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" id="link-1-1-1-1" rel="external" href='example.chapter1-unit1-section1-part1.html'>Part 1</a>
            <a data-role="button" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" id="link-1-1-1-2" rel="external" href='example.chapter1-unit1-section1-part2.html'>Part 2</a>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="false" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 2</h3>I'm Part 2</li>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="false" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 3</h3>I'm Part 3</li>
        </ul>
        <ul data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-3">
            <h3>Section 2</h3>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 1</h3>I'm Part 1</li>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 2</h3>I'm Part 2</li>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 3</h3>I'm Part 3</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>

<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" class="expandable depth-1">
    <h3>Chapter 2</h3>
    <ul data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-2">
        <h3> Unit 1 </h3>
        <ul data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-3">
            <h3>Section 1</h3>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 1</h3>I'm Part 1</li>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 2</h3>I'm Part 2</li>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 3</h3>I'm Part 3</li>
        </ul>
        <ul data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-3">
            <h3>Section 2</h3>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 1</h3>I'm Part 1</li>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 2</h3>I'm Part 2</li>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 3</h3>I'm Part 3</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div> 
<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" class="expandable depth-1">
    <h3>Chapter 3</h3>
    <ul data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-2">
        <h3> Unit 1 </h3>
        <ul data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-3">
            <h3>Section 1</h3>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 1</h3>I'm Part 1</li>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 2</h3>I'm Part 2</li>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 3</h3>I'm Part 3</li>
        </ul>
        <ul data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-3">
            <h3>Section 2</h3>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 1</h3>I'm Part 1</li>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 2</h3>I'm Part 2</li>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 3</h3>I'm Part 3</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div> 
<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" class="expandable depth-1">
    <h3>Chapter 4</h3>
    <ul data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-2">
        <h3> Unit 1 </h3>
        <ul data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-3">
            <h3>Section 1</h3>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 1</h3>I'm Part 1</li>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 2</h3>I'm Part 2</li>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 3</h3>I'm Part 3</li>
        </ul>
        <ul data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-3">
            <h3>Section 2</h3>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 1</h3>I'm Part 1</li>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 2</h3>I'm Part 2</li>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-4"><h3>Part 3</h3>I'm Part 3</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You should use server-side code.

Comment: Or if there is no action on the HTML you're getting you could just copy it to your DOM, without the HTML file, otherwise you'd have to have access to the host where this is coming and set some flags, here is a nice read about this http://www.jquery4u.com/dom-modification/jquery-change-css-iframe-content/

Comment: Could you expand a bit on what you mean by the loaded HTML not having access to jQuery, etc? Is there javascript code in the html, or are you having jQuery actions/events that aren't being activated by interaction with the HTML?

Comment: Sure. I'd put it in a jsfiddle, but I'm not sure how to use the external js files with the fiddle.  But basically, the table of contents panel should have proper jquery mobile formatting as well as a few button controls that expand all of the list elements at once, collapse them all, or open the bookmarks.  The buttons are defined in bookmark2.js and linknavigation.js, and the example.toc.html file just calls each button by its id.  The buttons  don't work when I open the panel, and the panel shows up as plain html, instead of being formatted like jquery-mobile normally does.

Comment: If I copy all of the script tags from the head into the example.toc.html file, everything within the slide panel works.  Unfortunately, the main page references buttons from bookmark2.js and those buttons are no longer displayed properly, presumably because the scripts are now loaded twice and cause formatting errors.

Comment: If I understand your question well, you need to use `pagebeforeshow` or `pageshow` events to load the contents and then you should enhance the markup of the panel using `.trigger('pagecreate')`. Never use `.ready()` in JQM, ignore the answers below, they should be down voted.

Comment: So, should I use jquery-mobile's loadPage() function, or continue with the standard jquery load()?

Comment: I once answered a similar question, where I used `.load()` to load contents in a hidden div, and then copy specific items to the target div. here's a demo on inserting items dynamically http://fiddle.jshell.net/8yAdd/

Comment: I've been trying your suggestion with pagebeforeshow and pageshow, but I can't get the results I want.  Could you possibly post an example of the format that I might use to bind pagebeforeshow or pageshow to the event?  I've been trying it like this...`<script>
                    $( 'div' ).on( "pagebeforecreate", function( event ) {
                        $('#TOC').load('example.TOC.html').trigger('create')
                        //$('#test2').trigger('create')
                    })
                </script> `

Comment: Check this answer and the demo on how to load contents from a file. Ill explain tomorrow as I don't have access to PC now. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17271840/1771795

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36311/discussion-between-omar-and-ordanj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but I see two options:

1) You copy over all the necessary  tags from the original document to the TOC.html file

2) Try and wrapping that $.load into a $(document).ready / $(window).load and see what happens. I would put this in a regular comment but unfortunately I can't comment yet (need 50 rep).

Comment: I tried option 2 earlier, but I'll give it another go and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really set on doing this all serverside, then can you just wrap your load code in $(function(){ ...code here... }); ?

It seems like you could use a combination of that and load's [complete callback function](http://api.jquery.com/load/). The flow would go something like this:

1. Wait for the page to be loaded using .ready()
2. Fire off load()
3. In the complete() callback, append data to the page, applying any jquery mobile data attributes you might need to the page.

If you create a plunkr for this, we could do a working example.